# RHEL 7 installing tkinter with python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, yum, rhel7

I've disabled the subscription manager and registered a few repos, `epel` and `remi`, but am unable to install `tkinter`. Keep getting the error no package available. The only package available is for `python 3.4`. Was wondering whether anyone else had run into this issue. Not sure how to resolve it there's not a lot of documentation on the RHEL website.

I've also tried installing `tcl/tk` and yum can't seem to find these packages either. The one package with tcl in it it fails because of dependency problems. No luck with `yum groupinstall -y "development tools"` either. I'm mostly just trying to install `pyautogui` which requires `tkinter` be installed already.

Answer (score 0):

The tkinter package is in the `rhel-7-server-optional-rpms` repo, though I don't see pyautogui available in RHEL.

Your mileage may vary on whether tkinter is at the right version needed.

Comment: To enable optional RPMs see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47843159/623541